# How to compare variable values from multiple objectives

Tags: java

I've just started with java so bear with me if I confuse things.

Anyway, I want to create a level that contains 4 different rooms. I've done it so that every room is a seperate object which is created in the main method.

What I want to do then is to place every room inside a level of a certain size, and if a room overlaps another it will return false. Every room is basically a block of 100x100 pixels.

I've done so that every room object stores it's location on the level when placed by assigning the (x,y) cords to 2 variables defined within the room class.

But I run into trouble when placing the second room. How do I check if the second room I want to place doesn't overlap with the others? My tought was that you check all the (x,y) variable values in all the room objects and if any of them overlaps it will return false. However I don't know how to refer to all these variables, how can I check the variables in every room object?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Consider modelling a *collection* of rooms. The disjointness test is then a function of that *collection*. Each room will hold its length and width (and provide functions to return those) but *not* its position in space. That again is a property of the collection.

Comment: create an ArrayList and call it level, you can add rooms to the level ArrayList and keep track of them.

ArrayList level = new ArrayList();
       String room1 [][] = new String [100][100]; 
       String room2 [][] = new String [100][100];
       level.add(room1);
       level.add(room2);

Answer (score 0):

Place the rooms that are assigned to a place in an `ArrayList`, so you can loop through them and compare the parameters. I suppose a room does not only have `x` and `y` coordinates, but also `length` and `width`.

```
// using a list of rooms that are placed on level
List<Room> assignedRooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
// create a new room (x, y, width, height)
Room newRoom = new Room(0, 0, 100, 100);
assignedRooms.add(newRoom);
// create further rooms
```

In order to find out whether a room overlaps with another one or not, you best loop through the remaining rooms, i.e., the ones you have already placed within the whole area and check if the `x` and `y` coordinates of the newly added room are in conflict with any of the other rooms.

```
for (int i = 0; i < assignedRooms.size(); i++) {
    Room assignedRoom = assignedRooms.get(i);
    if (assignedRoom.x < roomToAdd.x && assignedRoom.x + assignedRoom.width > roomToAdd.x) 
        // overlap
        return false;
    else if (assignedRoom.y < roomToAdd.y && assignedRoom.y + assignedRoom.height > roomToAdd.y)
        // overlap
        return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: I disagree, the position should be a property of the *collection*, not the room.

Comment: That is a possible realization of that problem, but the question simply was how to check the variables of all the different objects. I agree that your approach is more effective, but then again not the solution/answer the OP is looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answear, so basically what you do is everytime a room is placed on the level instead of storing the location in the room object, you place the location in an array that is later looped through when adding a second and a third room.

Comment: Maybe an `ArrayList` or some other collection is more advisable as you cannot know how many rooms you add at the very beginning. I do no place the locations in an array/collection, but the `Room`s (and I access the locations via the `Room` objects). Then I can check for each new `Room` whether an already added `Room` occupies a location.

Comment: @Carl did it work or do you have any further questions?